# cirq.ControlledGate from sub-circuit generator

Tags: programming, cirq

In Cirq, is it possible to take a sub-circuit generator and use it as the `sub_gate` in a `cirq.ControlledGate`?

```
... instantiate circuit and qubits q0-q3 ...

... define sub circuit generator:
def my_layer():
    """
    sub-circuit generator
    ref: https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/docs/circuits.md
    """
    yield CZ(q0, q1)
    yield [H(q) for q in (q0, q1, q2)]
    yield [CZ(q1, q2)]
    yield [H(q0), [CZ(q1, q2)]]

... take the sub-circuit generator and do something like:
gate = cirq.ControlledGate(sub_gate = my_layer())
circuit.append(gate(q3))
```

In other words, how can I take a sub-circuit and make its execution conditional on a control qubit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet will do almost what you want:

```
class MyLayerGate(cirq.Gate):
    def _decompose_(self, qubits):
        a, b, c = qubits
        return my_layer(a, b, c)

    # [will be unnecessary in v0.5.0] workaround for cirq.unitary ignoring _decompose_:
    def _unitary_(self):
        return cirq.unitary(
            cirq.Circuit.from_ops(self._decompose_(
                cirq.LineQubit.range(3))))

controlled_my_layer_gate = cirq.ControlledGate(MyLayerGate())
```

In the future, the `# workaround` part won't be necessary anymore. Currently it's needed because:

1) `cirq.ControlledGate` doesn't implement a `_decompose_` method. I've [opened an issue to fix this](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/1284).

2) `cirq.apply_unitary` and `cirq.unitary` should use `_decompose_` when `_unitary_` isn't implemented on a gate, so that circuit simulation works when using gates with nothing but a specified decomposition. There is an in-progress PR [to fix that](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/pull/1250).

Also, I do like the idea of controlling the gates coming out of a method without having to define a new class. A unified `cirq.control(callable_or_gate_or_operation, optional_specified_control)` method would be useful. I'll also open [an issue to do that](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/1285).